# How to cache Shopify cart items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, shopify

Hi I'm using mobile buy sdk to integrate Shopify in my app. I add product to the cart by using `[self.cart addVariant:self.productVariant];` .But my problem is whenever I close and open the app means cart shows empty. How to overcome this problem?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also working on Shopify SDK plz Help me in addToCart...
i passthis way on AddToCart 
Button=>[self.cart addVariant:(BUYProductVariant *)_product];
(BUYProductVariant *)_product]; is my variant value...But not working.
So, How can i add Item in AddToCart and Cart ?

Comment: create cart in appdelegate.h then access it to add and remove items.

Comment: This is my issue,....
https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-ios/issues/342
Please help me...

Comment: I also face this type issue...Cache cart items. I get all items in linecartitem....But again i run the app. not getting any item. how can i solve? plz help me...

Comment: Just store your product id i local database.You can see a function like getproductbyid(). You can use this function and get the product and then add product to cart.I did like this only.